# How can I increase height of container view to design with auto layout in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I want to design 5 views - they have different sizes, but I can't drag and drop 5 `UIView`s to my View Controller.

[image: No room for 5 views]

Where is the position for view 4 and view 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your view controller's **Simulated Size** attribute to Freeform inside the **Size inspector**. After that, you can enter any value you want there.

[image: Size inspector settings for view controller]

However, keep in mind that the size you are setting up here is only a **simulated size**. If you want your controller to be scrollable, you will have to set up a scroll view and put these views inside it.

Comment: Thanks. i am a newbie!